# Salesforce apex/visualforce check input field is a number

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I have an visualforce inputField that is linked to a currency field on a record:

```
<apex:inputField type="text" id="odNum" value="{!curRecap.Order_Number__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField id="totAm" type="text" value="{!curRecap.Total_Amount_Sold__c}" />
```

How can I ensure that the user enters a proper currency value in apex? Right now I have

```
if(curRecap.Order_Number__c == null || curRecap.Total_Amount_Sold__c == null) {
                isNumberInput = false;
                return;
            } else {
                isNumberInput = true;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex to validation value at server side(In apex code), 
or use Javascript Regex for validating at client side.